When we observe objects in a rotating frame, why do we apply centrifugal force radially outwards?
Suppose we have small ball placed gently in a  radial groove of a disk rotating at constant angular velocity. Why do we apply centrifugal force radially outwards?

Have you looked at the Wikipedia page on rotating motion, or any YouTube videos?  I ask because it's a very common topic, and those authors were able to put more time into an answer than an individual on stack exchange could.  If you've researched the topic, and have additional questions, can you please edit the question to focus on the aspects of centrifugal acceleration that are causing you confusion?

Could you clarify if you mean a radial groove or a concentric circular groove?

This question is similar to: What real force causes outward acceleration in rotation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the ball is rolling or sliding in the groove, so that it is not moving with the disk but is staying in one place, then, in the disk's rotating frame of reference, the roles are reversed and the ball is moving while the disk is standing still. Moving objects in a rotating frame of reference experience a Coriolis force. In this situation, the Coriolis force points inward and exactly balances the centrifugal force.
This is a situation where the rotating coordinate system is especially unhelpful.

Doesn't  coriolis force always act perpendicular to objects velocity.. if we see with respect to the rotating  frame won't normal  reaction between the grooves cancel out the coriolis force
